# How to replace patterns matching `{ + (anything) + }` with `{ + (anything) + :: + (anything) + }` in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with some text, with some important items marked with beginning and closing braces, e.g.:

```
Once upon a {time}, there lived a rabbit.
The {rabbit lived} in a small house.
One day, the {rabbit visited }the {mountains}.
In the mountains, he {found} a tree with 10{,000} branches.
```

I need to replace any items in the `{x}` form with `{x::x}`, e.g.:

```
Once upon a {time::time}, there lived a rabbit.
The {rabbit lived::rabbit lived} in a small house.
One day, the {rabbit visited ::rabbit visited }the {mountains::mountains}.
In the mountains, he {found::found} a tree with 10{,000::,000} branches.
```

- Every opening `{` has a matching `}` on the same line.
- Braces never split across lines.
- Braces are never nested.
- Any kind of symbols might appear between the `{` and `}`'s.

I tried several approaches with `sed`, but nothing worked, e.g.:

```
sed 's/{(.*)}/{&::&}/g' file.txt
```

How can I replace all items in the braces, e.g. `{some word}` with the pattern `{some word::some word}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easier if you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -ple 's/{(.*?)}/{$1::$1}/g' file
Once upon a {time::time}, there lived a rabbit.
The {rabbit lived::rabbit lived} in a small house.
One day, the {rabbit visited ::rabbit visited }the {mountains::mountains}.
In the mountains, he {found::found} a tree with 10{,000::,000} branches.
```

It matches all things inside curly brace `{...}` **non-greedy**, then replace it with desired string `{$1::$1}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the fix

```
sed 's/{\([^}]*\)}/{\1::\1}/g' file

Once upon a {time::time}, there lived a rabbit.
The {rabbit lived::rabbit lived} in a small house.
One day, the {rabbit visited ::rabbit visited }the {mountains::mountains}.
In the mountains, he {found::found} a tree with 10{,000::,000} branches.
```

#### Explanation

- `[^}]*` match the non-`}`chars
- `\(...\)` would capture the characters specified inside of the parens and \1 would be used to reference the first match, this is a part of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
sed 's/\([^{]*{\)\([^}]*\)\(}.*\)/\1\2::\2\3/'
```

Not tested

Comment: will only work on string that have 1 `{}` and you take to many character around (not needed to take so much look @BMW solution).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` variant:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""} NR%2==0{$0="{"$0"::"$0"}"} 1' RS='[{}]' file.txt

Once upon a {time::time}, there lived a rabbit.
The {rabbit lived::rabbit lived} in a small house.
One day, the {rabbit visited ::rabbit visited }the {mountains::mountains}.
In the mountains, he {found::found} a tree with 10{,000::,000} branches.
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `ORS=RS` when `RS` is a regex & I want to use only `{` or only `}` as applicable (not `[{}]`)?

Comment: One advantage over other answers (may not be very useful for current input, but still..): If the text in `{}` contains an embedded new-line, it is also handled.